# Avoid to pay a huge bill with Firestore when updating users location

Tags: firebase, flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently writing a location app and I'm facing an issue: I need to update the location of each connected user in order to detect user's moves. I use Firestore to store these locations and **the price for 100K writes is 0.18$.**

Let's say that 10k users use the app 30min in a day, with a refresh interval of 5 seconds:

10.000 * (30*60) / 5 = 3.6M write operations = ~ $6.48/day = ~ **$195/month.**

I find this really expensive given that we consider only 10k users with a daily time use of just 30min.
Is it a normal bill for this kind of app ?

Is there a method to decrease this bill ?

Comment: You have to start charging them. I created inventory web app and I plan to charge customers small fee(2x costs)